# get a relative series of numbers

Tags: javascript, math, modulo

I have an array of indexes (for instance): [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9] and a constant value (for instance 2).
Based on this array I would like to find a sequence of numbers as follow:

```
0 -> 0
1 -> 0
2 -> 0
3 -> 0
4 -> 0
5 -> 1
6 -> 1
7 -> 1
8 -> 1
9 -> 1
```

Could any body help me to figure out the right logic for computing the value to the right of the arrow based on the value on the left and the constant value?

*(in this example my contant value is two but it could be bigger. My sequence of number can also be much larger).*

Doing `index % MY_CONSTANT_VALUE` is not quite what I am looking for since it returns the following sequence:

```
0 -> 0
1 -> 1
2 -> 0
3 -> 1
4 -> 0
...
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The question is not clear

Comment: Please read [ask] and post your efforts in a [mcve]

Comment: What is the logic necessary to derive the values to the right of the arrow? Does "for instance 2" mean half of the indexes of the array?

Comment: (index > 4) % MY_CONSTANT_VALUE

Comment: @Lam Pham. This works for the very simple case I posted as an example. However if my sequence is much bigger and that my contant value is bigger it doesn't work

Comment: To clarify: if MY_CONSTANT_VALUE = 4. What is the answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like what you want is `Math.floor(index / MY_CONSTANT_VALUE)`. It's basically integer division. How many times does `MY_CONSTANT_VALUE` **completely** go into `index`?

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could take the length of the array to get the part number for a given index.

```js
var indices = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
    parts = 2;
    
console.log(indices.map((i, _, a) => Math.floor(i * parts / a.length)));
```